# Cannot add a row to my database without getting 'Illegal Characters in path" error

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am a beginner with Visual Basic.

At the moment I am having a problem with my program where anytime I try and add to a row in my database visual studio flags up an "Illegal characters in path" error.

Here is a snippet of the relevant areas of my code:

```
Dim customerAdapter As New CustomerDetailsTableAdapters.tblCustomerDetailsTableAdapter
Dim customerTable As CustomerDetails.tblCustomerDetailsDataTable
Dim customerRow As CustomerDetails.tblCustomerDetailsRow
Dim customerDataSet As CustomerDetails

Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        customerAdapter.AddCustomer(Forename:="test", Surname:="test",
                                    HouseNumber:="test", StreetName:="test",
                                    Postcode:="test", Email:="test",
                                    Telephone:="test", Mobile:="test",
                                    PreferredContact:="test")


End Sub
```

I have checked that the data types are correct.

I am working in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and I am using .NET Framework 4.
Another thing you should know is that I have one column in the table that is auto incremental by one and currently the table is empty upon start up.

Comment: Perhaps this question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738331/entity-framework-illegal-characters-in-path-connection-string-mvc3

Comment: Sorry it is in c# could you possibly explain it for me please?

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of slow Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 SQL and installed Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 instead. Turns out something in SQL Server Compact 4.0 that had broken. I did try re-installing 2012 and SQL 4.0 but no good fortune. At least 2010 works :)